# Sitefinity - How to add link to internal page

Tags: sitefinity

I'm new to Sitefinity. So far I see some built in widgets to add image and text and let other edit them later on. However, I want to build a block which contains an image, a short description and when click that block will jump to an internal page. I'm stuck at figuring out how to make the internal URL editable.

Anybody has experience about this?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Harry, just check the corresponding forum post that you've created or my blogpost: http://knstr.it/GEYsOj

Comment: Hi Daniel, please post it as a reply and I will mark it as the answer :)